# How to display one component's input value to another components using props in REACTJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-component

This is a simple project where I want to display **firstComponent's** input value to another components (**secondComponent**) but I am failed to display another component. Now, I need the suggestion to do this projects and I have given the codes in below,

> App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import First from './components/firstComponent';
import Second from './components/secondComponent';

function App() {
return (
<div className="App">
<br/><br/>
<First />
<hr/> <hr>
<Second/>
</div>
);
}

export default App;
```

> firstComponent.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

const firstComponent = ()=> {
function handleChange(event) {
const inputValue = event.target.value;
console.log(inputValue);
}
return (
<div>
<h1><u>First Component</u> </h1>
<input type="text" style={{ width: "500px", height:"30px" }} onChange={handleChange}/>
</div>
)
}

export default firstComponent
```

;

> secondComponent.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

const secondComponent = (props) => {
return (
<div>
  <h1><u>Second Component</u> </h1>
  <h4>{this.props.inputValue}</h4>
</div>
)
}

export default secondComponent;
```

Note: I have attached the output page in attach file section, please concern there.

[image]

Comment: You need to have a relation between First and Second component. The second component does not receive any props from First one.

Comment: Redux is a common way to deal with this. First would put a value in Redux and Second would get it from Redux. Whenever the value is changed, Redux will cause a refresh of the Second component for you. It's a bit heavy to setup but worth it in my opinion

Comment: No doubt Redux will help here but we also have a solution in React itself which is context API just wrap both component in context api and `FirstComponent` will be Producer and `Secondcomponent` will be Consumer.

Comment: You could also have the input to be a state in the `App` component where u pass down the setState method to the firstComponent und pass the value to the second component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the code given below. This will hopefully fulfill your requirement.

App.js

```
import FirstComponent from './FirstComponent'
const App = () => {
    return ( 
       <>
        <FirstComponent / >
        </>
    )
}

export default App
```

FirstComponent.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import SecondComponent from "./error";

function FirstComponent() {
  const [inputData, setInputData] = useState();

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h1>
          <u>First Component</u>{" "}
        </h1>
        <input
          type="text"
          style={{ width: "500px", height: "30px" }}
          onChange={(e) => setInputData(e.target.value)}
        />
        <br />
        <SecondComponent inputValue={inputData} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
export default FirstComponent;
```

SecondComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';

const secondComponent = (props) => {
return (
<div>
  <h1><u>Second Component</u> </h1>
  <h4>{props.inputValue}</h4>
</div>
)
}

export default secondComponent;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are right, it's working.